# destroy a wall that is useless

Tags: walls, concrete-block, removal

I'm new to building or destroying things in that occasion.

I have a wall that is not supporting the roof or any other part of the house.

Removing that wall will help me build an extension of a room in my house.

I want to use a <s>mace</s> sledgehammer to destroy that wall.

Are there a better solution less consuming in time and effort than use a <s>mace</s> sledgehammer, please?

Second question is :  Are there other factors should I check when trying to remove a wall in my house than checking the wall is supporting part of the roof?

Any of your advices would be welcome.

Cheers.

Comment: How do you know it's not supporting anything?  Any possibility of plumbing or electrical in the wall?

Comment: Hi, no nothing. I thought it was supporting something actually it is a useless wall

Comment: If you're sure the wall is not load bearing, and there's not electric, plumbing, or ducting in the wall. Then go at it with the mace. You'll likely have quite a mess to clean up, but it will probably be enough fun to make up for it.

Comment: Now I want to know what you're calling a "Mace", because I'm picturing you going after the wall with a medieval spiked ball on a handle. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mace_%28weapon%29  Is it like a sledgehammer?

Comment: A mace (sledgehammer) would surely make a lot of small debris to pick up. My demo tools are reciprocating saw, 20 oz curved claw hammer, crow bar and short ripping bar. Everything comes down in large chunks, big enough to be a lot to carry. Small debris is at a minimum.

Comment: By the way, I'm picturing you swinging something like [this](http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/merlin1/images/6/63/Mace.png/revision/latest?cb=20120402105106) at the wall.

Comment: @Tester101: I meant sledgehammer but instead the word mace came out of my mind. Lol :))) Thanks :)))))

Comment: As G.K. Chesterton [pointed out](http://stuartbuck.blogspot.com/2004/05/chesterton_14.html), you probably should not "clear it away" until you understand why it was there in the first place.

Comment: Hi @jasper, issue is the previous owner has left a while ago. How should I proceed with the retro engineering of the house?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brick Walls are usually load bearing or non-load bearing. Generally you can identify them by their width. While not "best practice", in some cases a connecting non-load bearing wall may act as a lateral brace to a long load bearing wall. This may be an issue in an earth-quake prone area where bracing walls are very important. Check with your local building codes for that.

Other than that, make sure you disconnect/reroute all services that run through- and inside and then demolish away. You may want to perforate the wall first, by either cutting it or drilling holes, especially where you want to disconnect the wall from the building.

The impact of a sledgehammer might cause unwanted superficial damage outside the area you are busy demolishing. Perforating and then using a crow bar/ripping bar may be a better solution.